# How to get an Batch file .bat continue onto the next statement if there is an error

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to script the shutdown of my VM Servers in a .bat.
if one of the vmware-cmd commands fails (as the machine is already shutdown say), I'd like it to continue instead of bombing out.

```
c:
cd "c:\Program Files\VMWare\VmWare Server"

vmware-cmd C:\VMImages\TCVMDEVSQL01\TCVMDEVSQL01.vmx suspend soft -q
vmware-cmd C:\VMImages\DevEnv\DevEnv\DevEnv.vmx suspend soft -q
vmware-cmd C:\VMImages\DevEnv\TCVMDEV02\TCVMDEV02.vmx suspend soft =q


robocopy c:\vmimages\ \\tcedilacie1tb\VMShare\DevEnvironmentBackups\ /mir /z /r:0 /w:0

vmware-cmd C:\VMImages\TCVMDEVSQL01\TCVMDEVSQL01.vmx start
vmware-cmd C:\VMImages\DevEnv\DevEnv\DevEnv.vmx start 
vmware-cmd C:\VMImages\DevEnv\TCVMDEV02\TCVMDEV02.vmx start
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Run it inside another command instance with `CMD /C`

```
CMD /C vmware-cmd C:\...
```

This should keep the original BAT files running.

Answer (score 7):

If you are calling another batch file, you must use CALL batchfile.cmd

Comment: I was calling several batch files (query1.bat query2.bat) from a main job (morning.bat) and any time one of the little .bat files hit an error like "file not found" when cleaning up old logs, the whole thing would stop. This did the trick. +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using "start (cmd)" for each command you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little Program that executes the command an returns a value (say -1 for an error). This value can then be used in your Batch-File.

Answer (score 0):

A batch file should continue executing, even if the previous command has generated an error.  Perhaps, what you are seeying is the batch aborting due to some other error?